# Region Manager can not find region inside of the custom popupwindow

Tags: prism

I have a ShellView using interactivity objects with prism's PopupWindowAction for show my custom settings view. And my ShellViewModel contain InteractionRequest object and a Delegate Command that will fire the user interaction. After user fired interaction, custom settings view (DataFeedManagerView) appear center of ShellView. In My DataFeedManagerView, there is a list of DataFeeds (ListBox control) on the left side and there is datafeed specific settings view (ContentControl with set Region via RegionManager) on the right side. First, i registered all Views with RegisterViewWithRegion. Then what i try to do is activate related object settings view within content control via Region's Activate method. When i try to do like this, i'm receiving an error "can not find region". So we can not use regions inside custom popup window???

PS1: Maybe this is so simple requirement but containing many steps because of that my explanation was a little bit complicated. I hope code will be more descriptive.

PS2: I meet expectations with using simple binding to ContentControl's content property. But i'm worry about what is my mistake and/or right solution for use regions inside custom interaction popup window.

..::Shell::..

```
<Window x:Class="PrismUnityApp.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PrismUnityApp.Views"
    xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:PrismUnityApp.Constants"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="480" Width="640">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ConfirmationRequest}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:DataFeedManagerView/>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Button Content=" Show Data Feed Manager" Command="{Binding ShowDataFeedManagerCommand}"/>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:WellKnownRegionNames.ContentRegion}" />
</DockPanel>
```

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace PrismUnityApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";
        public ICommand ShowDataFeedManagerCommand { get; }
        public InteractionRequest<IConfirmation> ConfirmationRequest { get; }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>();
            ShowDataFeedManagerCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowDataFeedManager);
        }
        public void ShowDataFeedManager()
        {
            ConfirmationRequest.Raise(
                new Confirmation {Title = "Data Feed Manager", Content = string.Empty},
                confirmation =>
                {
                });
        }
    }
}
```

..::DataFeedManager::..

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrismUnityApp.Views.DataFeedManagerView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:PrismUnityApp.Constants"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         Height="240" Width="320">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ListBox
        SelectedItem="{Binding Current, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataFeeds}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></prism:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:WellKnownRegionNames.DataFeedRegion}"></ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Regions;
using PrismUnityApp.Constants;
using PrismUnityApp.Interfaces;

namespace PrismUnityApp.ViewModels
{
    public class DataFeedManagerViewModel : BindableBase, IDataFeedManagerViewModel
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
        public IDictionary<string, object> DataFeeds { get; }
        public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand { get; }
        public DataFeedManagerViewModel(IUnityContainer unityContainer, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;

            SelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(SelectionChanged);

            DataFeeds = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {WellKnownDataFeedNames.SimulationDataFeed, unityContainer.Resolve<ISimulationDataFeedView>()},
                {WellKnownDataFeedNames.BarchartDataFeed, unityContainer.Resolve<IBarchartDataFeedView>()}
            };

            foreach (var dataFeed in DataFeeds)
                _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(WellKnownRegionNames.DataFeedRegion, () => dataFeed.Value);
        }
        public void SelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var addedItem = (KeyValuePair<string, object>) e.AddedItems[0];
            var region = _regionManager.Regions[WellKnownRegionNames.DataFeedRegion];
            region.Activate(addedItem.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

..::Bootstrapper::..

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Unity;
using PrismUnityApp.Interfaces;
using PrismUnityApp.ViewModels;
using PrismUnityApp.Views;

namespace PrismUnityApp
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        #region Overrides of UnityBootstrapper

        protected override void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            base.ConfigureContainer();
            Container.RegisterType<ISimulationDataFeedView, SimulationDataFeedView>();
            Container.RegisterType<ISimulationDataFeedViewModel, SimulationDataFeedViewModel>();
            Container.RegisterType<IBarchartDataFeedView, BarchartDataFeedView>();
            Container.RegisterType<IBarchartDataFeedViewModel, BarchartDataFeedViewModel>();
            Container.RegisterType<IDataFeedManagerView, DataFeedManagerView>();
            Container.RegisterType<IDataFeedManagerViewModel, DataFeedManagerViewModel>();
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<ShellView>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you need to set the region manager manually, in the popup view's code behind (constructor), like this:

```
RegionManager.SetRegionName( theNameOfTheContentControlInsideThePopup, WellKnownRegionNames.DataFeedRegion );
RegionManager.SetRegionManager( theNameOfTheContentControlInsideThePopup, theRegionManagerInstanceFromUnity );
```

You'll have to assign a name to the content control hosting the region and somehow acquire the region manager (`ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>()`).

Comment: Where are the regionManager's SetRegionName & SetRegionManager methods?

Comment: These are static members called on the type and not on the concrete `IRegionManager` instance

Comment: Well my problem is solved but; Is solution breaking MVVM pattern? or Is problem something like a bug about Prism Library? Don't know. What is your thoughts about these issues?

Comment: You don't break MVVM. The xaml-"shortcut" for setting the region name works only for regions that the region manager can find by traversing the visual tree. Your popup needs the region manager manually set, and that cannot be done through xaml... and it isn't _that_ much code in the code behind, and it won't interfer with your tests, because you don't test the view in unit tests, anyway.

Comment: Isn't the first line doing exactly what the OP's XAML is doing: `<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:WellKnownRegionNames.DataFeedRegion}"></ContentControl>`?

Comment: With the difference that the code-behind version runs when the control is created while the xaml version runs when the owning control is created. When the popup is created, the region manager is long created and just does not care for the xaml in the popup.