# Prism region inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I've implemented a `WizardControl` (which is represented by an `UserControl` and the associated `ViewModel`). This wizard should navigate without prism - it has its own logic.

The wizard pages are registered with `DataTemplates`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewAViewModel}">
        <view:ViewAView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewBViewModel}">
        <view:ViewBView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
...

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Content="Prev" Command="{Binding PrevCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

The `CurrentPage` is selected by wizards `ViewModel`.

On a specific wizard page i want to use a prism `Region`

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="InnerRegion" />
```

But when I call `_regionManager.RequestNavigate(...)` the region inside the `RegionManager` is never created.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a good reason to do this, you can set the region name and the region manager from code-behind as described [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212881/region-manager-can-not-find-region-inside-of-the-custom-popupwindow/41228367#41228367)...

Basically you put these lines in `ViewA`'s constructor:

```
RegionManager.SetRegionName( theNameOfTheContentControlInsideViewA, "viewARegionName" );
RegionManager.SetRegionManager( theNameOfTheContentControlInsideViewA, ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>() );
```

Comment: This did not work. The `_regionManager.Regions` in my `ViewAViewModel` did not contains the region name. So `RequestNavigate` fails.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in viewA's constructor, does it get hit before you're trying to navigate? Does it operate on the same region manager instance?

Comment: Okay thats weird. `OnNavigatedTo` is called before the views constructor...

Comment: Why do you have to use a region within the wizard page? If you had the view model you want to navigate to, you could just expose it from `ViewAViewModel` and bind to viewA's content control directly.